# What is the principle behind R's fisher.test for calculating odds ratio, p-value, and the 95% CI?Why is the manually calculated OR different?

Tags: r, fishers-exact-test

There is a 2×2 matrix
[image]
The manully calculated OR is 25, however, it is different from the odds ratio calculated by the fisher.test function in R,what is the principle behind R's fisher.test for calculating odds ratio, p-value, and the 95% CI?
[image]